# count the value from multidimantional array

Tags: php, arrays

i have array :-

```
Array
(
[id] => 1
[aid] => 2
[views] => 1731
)

Array
(
[id] => 3
[aid] => 2
  [views] => 4421
)

Array
(
[id] => 1
[aid] => 1
[views] => 6136
)
```

I have above array i want to show the same key together with total of the views

```
$aidArray=array();

foreach($data as $key=>$row){
   // creating array for aid
   if(!in_array($row['aid'], $aidArray)){
   $aidArray[] = $row['aid'];
}

}
```

the above array returns

```
Array
(
[0] => 1
[1] => 3
)
```

i also want to calculate the total of the 'views' for each same aid.

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP 5.5 array_column()

```
$myArray = array(
    array( 'id' => 1, 'aid' => 2, 'cid' => 3, 'sid' => 1, 'tid' => 100000, 'views' => 1731 ),
    array( 'id' => 2, 'aid' => 2, 'cid' => 4, 'sid' => 1, 'tid' => 100000, 'views' => 4421 ),
    array( 'id' => 3, 'aid' => 1, 'cid' => 7, 'sid' => 3, 'tid' => 100001, 'views' => 6136 ),
);

$aidArray = array();
foreach(array_unique(array_column($myArray,'aid')) as $aid) {
    $aidArray[$aid] = array_sum(array_column(
        array_filter(
            $myArray,
            function($value) use ($aid) {
               return $value['aid'] == $aid;
            }
        ),
        'views'
    ));
}

var_dump($aidArray);
```

gives

```
array(2) {
  [2]=>
  int(6152)
  [1]=>
  int(6136)
}
```

**EDIT**

For versions of PHP prior to 5.5 (uses closures, so does require >= 5.3)

```
$aidArray = array();
foreach(array_unique(array_map(function($value) {return $value['aid']; }, $myArray)) as $aid) {
    $aidArray[$aid] = array_sum(array_map(
        function($value) {return $value['views']; },
        array_filter(
            $myArray,
            function($value) use ($aid) {
               return $value['aid'] == $aid;
            }
        )
    ));
}
```

Comment: Don't simply say "not working".... not working means what? Does it throw any error messages? Does it return wrong values (it shouldn't because I tested it myself)? Does it give you a blank screen? Does it eat your pet gerbil? Does it etc...

Comment: it says "Call to undefined function array_column()"

Comment: my php version is 5.4
and the araay_column works for PHP >= v5.5.
 can you please update your code acc. to php version 5.4 ?

Comment: I think the first line in my answer told you that this answer required PHP >= 5.5

Comment: yes i have read that.. so can you help me with the php 5.4 version?
waiting for your ans.